# Transform date string to another format in Swift

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I'm a beginner in Swift and I'm getting a date from a JSON snippet in string format, yyyy-MM-dd. For example:

```
2017-09-20
```

How do I display it in dd/MM/yyyy format?

```
20/09/2017
```

I am trying the following:

```
var dateString =  item["data"] as! String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print(date)
```

But my result when printed is null.

Comment: Your date format needs to match the original string to convert it to a Date.

Comment: As always, you are missing a piece. It's StringRepresentingDate => DateFormatterWithFormatCorrespondingToPreviousString => Date => DateFormatterWithFormatCorrespondingToTargetString => FinalString. That's the logic.

Comment: Obviously you know the format is `yyyy-MM-dd` so I'm wondering why do you pass `dd-MM-yyyy`?

Answer (score 5):

Helper Method for changing date format to another format:

```
class Helper {

static func changeDateFormat(dateString: String, fromFormat: String, toFormat: String) ->String {
    let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = fromFormat
    let date = inputDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    let outputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputDateFormatter.dateFormat = toFormat
    return outputDateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
}
```

Now, Where you want to use this method, just call helper class with the required params

```
println(Helper.changeDateFormat(dateString: "2017-09-20", fromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd", toFormat: "yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're converting the string to a date, you need the `dateFormat` to match the format of the string: `yyyy-MM-dd`. Then you would use a second `DateFormatter` with the output format to display it.

```
var dateString =  item["data"] as! String
let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = inputDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

let outputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
print(outputDateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

If this code is going to be running more than a few times, you should probably reuse the `DateFormatter` instances instead of recreating them each time, because it's an expensive class to create.